# Bootstrap datepicker issues on small screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a datepicker inside a Bootstrap modal.  It works good on normal screen. But I have the following issues on small mobile screen

1) On normal screen the datepicker displays right below the input field which is correct, but on small screen it moves further down and there is a gap between input field and datepicker.  I want to the datepicker position to be fixed always on every screen size.

2) On small screen if the datepicker is the last control it gets cut off at the bottom of the screen and we can't select the last dates of the month, there should be a scroll bar that allows you to scroll and select the last dates

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_start").datepicker({
          todayBtn: 1,
          autoclose: true,
          format: 'm/d/yyyy',
          orientation: "bottom",
          daysOfWeekHighlighted: "0,6",
        //  container: $('#listModal'),
      })
          .on('changeDate', function (selected) {
              var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
              $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_end').datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);

          }
      );
```